# Get properties of a Backbone model starting with certain text using Underscore.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a Backbone Model in which there are certain properties like

```
test_id
test_name
test_desc
test_score
```

Now I want to retrieve properties which are starting with **"test_"**.

I tried with code below and its working fine.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    getTestProperties: function(str){
       // get clone of attributes to iterate over
       var testProperties = {};
       var attrs = _.clone(this.attributes);
       _.each(attrs, function(val, key){
              if(key.indexOf(str) == 0){
                  testProperties[key]= val;
              }
           }, this);
    }
});
```

But
Is there any other way I can get these properties using underscore methods ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone proxies [some methods from Underscore on models](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-Underscore-Methods) that can help you create a more readable [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter): [`_.keys`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys) and [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick)

You can then simplify your function like this :

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    getTestProperties: function (str) {
        // get the keys you want
        var keys = _.filter(this.keys(), function (key) {
            return key.indexOf(str) === 0;
        });

        // and build an object
        return this.pick(keys);
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/5a63c/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
var attrs = _.filter(_.keys(_.clone(this.attributes)), function(attr){
  return attr.indexOf("text_") === 0;
});
```